# Difference between register_interceptor and after_actions in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, sidekiq

I am using `rails 5` along with `Amazon SES`.
I wanted to throttle emails before sending them because SES isn't able to handle bulk emails in a short span and mail jobs are failing.

So I wanted to add a `sidekiq` worker with rate limiting.

From  where should I call the worker, `mail_interceptor` or `after_actions`.

PS. In general what is the difference between them?

Answer (score 0):

There is vast difference.

**mail_interceptor**

When using an ActionMailer in Rails, there is a way to hook into an outbound message after calling "Deliver" method, but before delivery agents actually send it. You can think of these interceptors in the controller as before_action filter.
If you need to do any sort of modification before actually deliver, you will need to use an Interceptor.

**after_action**

This is a callback for controllers, use for perform something after completion of method or action.

Please refer [this](https://www.leighhalliday.com/mail-interceptors-and-observers) for more understanding.

Comment: Can you explain which one to use in which use case?

Comment: It's totally up to you but based on requirement I think mail_interceptor is perfect for you.

Comment: I am still not able to understand the difference between the two and why is it better in this case?

Comment: I am simply calling an action_mailer class with deliver_now. I have a very straight question what is the difference between the two, the link you provided doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

**The Problem**

Based on my understanding of your question, the problem here is a low level design question of where to place the code to throttle and send emails.

**Difference between `after_action` and `mail_interceptor` as per my understanding**

The use case of after_action,fairly straight forward, is to do something after certain action is executed.

The `mail_interceptor` on the other hand, is a hook that can be added in action mailer's mail delivery life cycle. As I understand, the purpose of the interceptor, is to modify certain email content or restrict sending email to users or restricting sending emails in certain environment before handling to the delivery agent. The use case is more concerned with **whether to send or what to send or to whom to send  rather than how to send.**

**Where to place the code?**

Also, the interceptor gets called on all email deliveries, since it is hooked to the life cycle of . For example, in case of a reset password email, I am assuming there is no necessity to throttle and is not necessary to call this piece of code.

Based on the above assumptions and understanding, my opinion is placing the code to throttle emails in the `after_action` makes more sense than placing it in the `mail_interceptor`.

Hope this was helpful!